# Create a list of data frames from list of data frame names (for merge_all)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I have a list of data frame names and I want to create a data frame list (or I want to be able to use the data frame name list to call the data frame itself). The idea is to be able to merge all data frames com a list of data frames names.

I have an example below where the mistake I am making is clear: when I refer to the list of data frame names, I merge the names themselves, not the data frames that the names refer to:

```
names.df<-c("red","green","blue")
variables.df<-c(1, 2, 3)

for(i in 1:length(names.df)){
assign(names.df[i],as.data.frame(i*variables.df))
}

df<-Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(names.df))
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Thank you! Don´t you want to answer the question below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data.frames (`red`, `blue`, and `green`) already exist in the environment, you should be able to do

```
mget(names.df)
```

It is not clear from your question if they already exist. If they do not, you have to go with a slightly different approach

```
setNames(object = lapply(seq_along(names.df), function(i){
    data.frame(val = variables.df * i)
}), nm = names.df)

#$red
#  val
#1   1
#2   2
#3   3

#$green
#  val
#1   2
#2   4
#3   6

#$blue
#  val
#1   3
#2   6
#3   9
```